# Can not upload pdf, jpg file at different server

Tags: php, mysql

Can not upload PDF, JPG,...  file at databases at different server?

I have a form on a one server and when they fill the data, data should be stored in a database on another server

```
function do_upload_files($id) {
    $allowed_doc_exts = "txt|pdf|jpg|jpeg|doc|odt|gif";
    $allowed_docs = 5;

    $ret = array();
    for ($i = "0"; $i <= $allowed_docs; $i++) {     
        $exts = explode("|", $allowed_doc_exts);

        $doc = "documents_" . $i;
        if (!isset($_FILES[$doc]))
            continue;

        if (empty($_FILES[$doc]["name"]))
            continue;

        $ext = pathinfo($_FILES[$doc]["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        if (!in_array(strtolower($ext), $exts))
            continue;       

$doc_dir = "/home/httpd/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/content/document/$id/";          
        if (!is_dir($doc_dir))
            mkdir($doc_dir, 0777, true);

        $doc_path = $doc_dir . $i;
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$doc]["tmp_name"], $doc_path)) {
            $ret[$i]["name"] = $_FILES[$doc]["name"];
            $ret[$i]["type"] = $_FILES[$doc]["type"];
        }
```

This is problem (i think):

```
$doc_dir = "/home/httpd/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/content/document/$id/";
```

Comment: What is the error message? At which point does it occur? etc. etc. etc

Comment: Try to check, what statement returns "false" or some other kind of errors.

Comment: @MikeW what do you mean? It IS possible to use POST forms to send data to another website.

Comment: Form upload all the data but it will not upload data at fields for documents (pdf, jpg, csv,..).

Comment: what does "it will not" means.. You get errors? You tried "exit;" at some points? Do some basic debugging before comming here. Otherwise we have to find the needle in the haystack.

Comment: When i put a form on the same server where the database then all well recorded in the database. But when I set the form and database on different servers then data will not be entered into the database for fields with the documents. 

I'm trying for two days to fix this. Server do not give me an error.

Comment: @Xatenev Maybe the path to another server, i need to write differently: **"/home/httpd/vhosts/doman-site/httpdocs/content/document/$id/"**  ` $doc_dir = "/home/httpd/vhosts/doman-site/httpdocs/content/document/$id/";   
   if (!is_dir($doc_dir))
    mkdir($doc_dir, 0777, true);
  
   $doc_path = $doc_dir . $i;
   if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$doc]["tmp_name"], $doc_path)) {
    $ret[$i]["name"] = $_FILES[$doc]["name"];
    $ret[$i]["type"] = $_FILES[$doc]["type"];
   }
  } `

Comment: You cant just put files there. You have to create some kind of API to put files on another server. Otherwise you could just put files on stackoverflow server for example.

Comment: @Nemanja I have created an answer on this.

Comment: [ http://www.introdizajn.com/db.txt ] This is link with code for db.php upload. With this code i upload data at another server database.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create some kind of API, on the server you wanna put files on. Otherwise you could just easily put files on stackoverflow server for example. So you have to create an API on the other server, who takes the files, and saves it onto the server. Aswell, you should password protect it, or you will be hacked very fast, if everybody can put files on your server.

On the other side, you just have to send data with a form, which contains the files.

Comment: [ http://introdizajn.com/db.txt ]  This is link with code for db.php upload. With this code i upload data at another server database.